# Como ajustar de forma dinámica un espacio entre una tabla y un static text en Jaspersoft

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft

Herramienta: Jaspersoft Studio 6.20.1

Tengo una tabla dinámica que se puede llenar hasta con 6 registros. Debajo de la tabla hay un campo con texto estático. Lo que necesito hacer es, que el espacio entre la tabla y el texto estático se ajuste de forma automática tomando en cuenta que tamaño tendrá la tabla.

Muchísimas gracias de antemano por sus respuestas

[image: Espacio entre tabla y texto]